# How to add 'priorities' to the primite 'n-of' in NetLogo?

Tags: list, netlogo

I have patches with 3 colors (yellow, green, and red). The green ones have a 'rank' value. I would like to ask a given number ('n-cells') of either yellow or green patches ('candidate-cells') to turn red. I am aware I can do that randomly using the primitive 'n-of', like this:

```
let candidate-cells ( patches with [ pcolor = yellow or pcolor = green ] )
ask n-of n-cells candidate-cells [ set pcolor red ]
```

But I would like add priorities to the patches that will be turned red. First, I would like yellow patches to turn red (randomly) but if there are still patches to be turned red after all patches yellow have, I would like green patches with highest 'rank' value to turn red until the number of turned patches reaches the 'n-cells' number. I **think** this piece of code should work till up its last line:

```
  let candidate-yellow-cells ( pcolor = yellow )
  let candidate-green-cells ( pcolor = green )

  ask n-of n-cells candidate-yellow-cells [ set pcolor red ]

  if n-cells > candidate-yellow-cells [
    let left-cells ( n-cells - candidate-yellow-cells )
    ask n-of left-cells candidate-green-cells [ set pcolor red ]
```

But still, I am using 'n-of' again for the green cells, I wonder how could I replace that by something that would pick the 'left-cells' as the green patches with highest 'rank' value. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should get you there:

```
globals [n-cells]
patches-own [rank]
to setup
  set n-cells 500
  ask patches [
    set pcolor one-of [yellow green red]
    set rank random 3
  ]
end

to recolor
  let _yellows (patches with [pcolor = yellow])
  let _ny count _yellows
  ifelse (n-cells > _ny) [
    ask _yellows [set pcolor red]
    let _greens sort-on [(- rank)] (patches with [pcolor = green])
    let _ng length _greens
    let _n min (list (n-cells - _ny) _ng)
    ask patch-set sublist _greens 0 _n [set pcolor red]
  ][
    ask n-of n-cells _yellows [
      set pcolor red
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Alan, once again you saved the day. Still, could anyone please clarify why we need the 'min' in: 'let _n min (list (n-cells - _ny) _ng)' ?

Comment: @ThalesWest  You cannot ask more patches than there are, so if you ask for too many, this just asks all there are.  An alternative is to consider asking for too many to be an error, but here I assumed you would want the program to keep running.